# Issue on multilanguage flutter application

Tags: flutter, amazon-dynamodb

I have tried to develop an mobile application that supports multiple languages. I have translated the content of my app and displayed, but if users use other languages keyboard and type content the AWS Dynamodb database accepts the language when retrieving to flutter it shows in à®®à®à¯à®·à¯à®µà®°à®¿ these type of characters. How to make flutter display same text as such in database.

I tried to display directly the retrieved data from database but it is not working, I need a solution to display all languages word in flutter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.